# Change Django many->one relationship to a many->many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

Hi have an existing Django model many->one relationship and I want to change it into a many->many relationship.  Can you do this with the same field, or do I have to create a parallel set of fields with a new many->many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define a new field and deal with transferring the old relationships to the new field.

A many->one relationship is just a column on your database storing the target table's PK's.

```
ID 1 <-> FK_ID 3
ID 2 <-> FK_ID 3
```

A many->many relationship involves an intermediary table, so it's a different beast.

```
ID 1 <-> m2m_table_id 1 <-> FK_ID 3
```

I'd set up a new field with the new m2ms, iterate over the current FK's and add them to the new M2M field.